# Nestjs: module structure and many-to-many relationships

Tags: nestjs, many-to-many, domain-driven-design

A thing that has been bothering me for a while is how to separate related aggregate roots into modules. For example, given a `documents` and an `authors` module, and the following endpoints:

- `/documents` to list all documents
- `/authors` to list all authors
- `/documents/:id/authors` to list authors of a document
- `/authors/:id/documents` to list documents of an author

How would we separate this into modules? I tend to think about NestJS modules as potentially being their own microservice.

**Option 1**

- `documents` module contains `DocumentsController` with both `/documents*` endpoints and `DocumentsRepository`. The `DocumentsRepository` has methods `list` and `listAuthorsForDocument(id)`
- `authors` module contains `AuthorsController` with both `/authors*` endpoints and `AuthorsRepository`. The `AuthorsRepository` has methods `list` and `listDocumentsForAuthor(id)`

This seems wrong, because the `DocumentsRepository` is purely meant for fetching and saving `Document` domain objects.

**Option 2**

- `documents` module contains `DocumentsController` with both `/documents*` endpoints and `DocumentsRepository`. The `DocumentsRepository` has methods `list` and `listByAuthor(id)`
- `authors` module contains `AuthorsController` with both `/authors*` endpoints and `AuthorsRepository`. The `AuthorsRepository` has methods `list` and `listByDocument(id)`

The `documents` module provides the `AuthorsRepository` so that `/documents/:id/authors` could use the `listByDocument` method. The `authors` module provides the `DocumentsRepository` so that `/authors/:id/documents` could use the `listByAuthor` method.

**Option 3**

- `documents` module contains `DocumentsController` which has the `/documents` and `/authors/:id/documents` endpoints and `DocumentsRepository`. The `DocumentsRepository` has methods `list` and `listByAuthor(id)`.
- `authors` module contains `AuthorsController` which has the `/authors` and `/documents/:id/authors` endpoints and `AuthorsRepository`. The `AuthorsRepository` has methods `list` and `listByDocument(id)`.

I guess I prefer option 3 as there are no imports between modules but it seems to into NestJSs way of defining endpoints (e.g. a `@Controller('/documents')` with endpoints `@Get()` for `/documents` and `@Get(':id/authors')` for `/documents/:id/authors`.

What are reasons to prefer on of these methods over the other or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter but if you want to be more consistent, here is another idea.

##### Module A

- Common Operations

##### Module B

- Common Operations

##### Module AB

- Relational Operations

This implementation might make your code more consistent.